# Python versions Windows 10 conundrum:

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, version, miniconda

I wanted to install latest Python 3.11 version.

I used the official download to install this, including making sure it appeared in the Environments path.

When I typed python-V in cmd, the version was 3.10

So I looked for this in the list of Windows programs, removed python 10. There was still a python 3.10.7 (64bit) in the programs list but that could not be removed.

I also ensured I uninstalled the 3.11 version using the official installer, then made sure I deleted the python/python3 exes that were still in appdata local.

Reinstalled 3.11 again and restarted.

3.11 was in the Environment path.

Typed in python -V and this time got  Python 3.9.10

So an even earlier version but cannot find this anywhere.

Typed in py -0 and got:

-V:3.11 *        Python 3.11 (64-bit)
-V:3.10          Python 3.10 (64-bit)

I am totally confused and do not know how to get 3.11 to be the selected version.

There was an Anaconda implementation on my machine at one time (miniconda3) but I opened the prompt for this and conda does not exist. I believe I removed this some time ago but maybe something is hanging around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use python 3.11 in cmd or terminal you should to do this:

```
python 3.11
```

because you have two version in your computer you should to do this
and if you using Vs-code you should change your interpreter to python 3.11